# Apollo graphQL subscription Which package to use

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions

I see for Apollo graphql if i wan to use plain Apollo subscription, I can import PubSub from `Apollo-server` or `graphql-subscription` . Wondering which one is correct to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at the [dependencies](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server/package.json#L28) of `apollo-server`.

`graphql-subscriptions` is the dependency of `apollo-server`.

`apollo-server` just [re-exports](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server/src/exports.ts#L2) all modules from `graphql-subscriptions` without modifying anything.

So, you can import `PubSub` from any package. They are the same.

Comment: Thanks . I have that in place . Not sure I see subscribe method is never called when I try from playground . In fact it’s not staying in listening mode .